# What if I forget to "feed" my wine?

Tags: fermentation, wine

I've been fermenting and "feeding" my wine for about 4 days. I am going somewhere and have to skip a day on "feeding" it. Feeding as in adding sugar and more flavoring. What happens if I skip to feed it for about 1-2 days? Will it go bad?

Answer (score 1):

Did you take hydrometer reading before you started?

Do you need to be feeding it, with sugar and flavours?

What yeast you using/are you following a recipe?

short answer, It will be fine just wont match your recipe and you would have invented something new!!